# Worklow Foundation(.NET) Equivalent for Python, Java, C++?

Tags: workflow

What is the Windows Workflow Foundation equivalent in Python, C++, Java?
I am looking for a classic and nice GUI based workflow framework to design
workflow GUIs with equivalent back end codes/activties or processes
Can anyone suggest?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [jBPM](http://www.jboss.org/jbpm/) for java. I have not come across anything similar for C++ and Python.

Answer (score 2):

Pure GUI workflows were a bit overrated.

We do not use GUI to construct iPhone software and HTML websites. We even stop using GUI for server administration. Also in 200x, it looks like no GUI approach can't succeed. All those Windows administration software and Borland products are dead now.

As opposite, we have a rise of open source code. Frameworks and libraries make software creation faster with code instead of GUI. Django, Ruby on Rails and Twitter Bootstrap, many server administration solutions like Ansible and Chef are great examples of such movement.

Honestly, for workflow software, such movement started not very long ago.

For Java you can take a look to [camunda](http://camunda.org), ruby has [ruote](https://github.com/jmettraux/ruote), and for python, I'm developing workflow library on top of django - [viewflow](http://viewflow.io/)

Comment: any comments on spiffWorkflow?